# GitLab external URL wrong

Tags: gitlab

Okay, so I just installed GitLab using the Omnibus edition on Ubuntu 14.04. I've got everything working, EXCEPT e-mail links and project URLs are using internal links (`http://gitlab/`). I've configured the external url parameter in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`, and I can't find any other settings to configure to possibly change this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after you change de external url you must reconfigure gitlab with `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`